# Pattern with Square Numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

I have noticed two patterns with square numbers.

$1^2\equiv 1\pmod{10}$

$2^2\equiv 4\pmod{10}$

$3^2\equiv 9\pmod{10}$

$4^2\equiv 6\pmod{10}$

$5^2\equiv 5\pmod{10}$

$6^2\equiv 6\pmod{10}$

$7^2\equiv 9\pmod{10}$

$8^2\equiv 4\pmod{10}$

$9^2\equiv 1\pmod{10}$

This set of numbers ${1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 4, 1}$ is palindromic (meaning it is the same backwards and forwards) and it rotates around $5$. In fact, it rotates around all odd multiples of $5$. And the set of ones digits of squares $6, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 6$ rotates around all even multiples of $5$.

That is the first pattern. If $|x-5|=|y-5|,$ then $x^2\equiv{y^2}\pmod{10}$.

The second pattern is similar, except it is bigger. If $|x-25|=|y-25|,$ then $x^2\equiv{y^2}\pmod{100}$.

My questions are: Why do these patterns work? Are the reasons related? And does this pattern appear with any other numbers?

Comment: $(10-y)^2\equiv(-y)^2\equiv y^2\pmod{10}$.  And did you mean $x^2\equiv y^2$ where you typed $x\equiv y$?

Comment: And ... $(50-y)^2=2500-100y+y^2\equiv y^2\pmod{100}$

Comment: Fix the typos in the palindromes.

Comment: $3^2\equiv\color{red}9\pmod{10}$

Comment: @Yves Daoust, sorry for the typos. I will fix them. And thanks for the answers!

Comment: Actually, it is meant to be $25$.

Comment: @Mathemagician314 That is why there is $50-y$: Numbers such as in the pairs  $(24,26)$, $(23,27)$ etc. have the same two last digits when squared precisely because "being at equal distance of $25$" in your context is the same as "they add up to $50$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single digit symmetry can be understood from the fact that $(-1)^2=1$.  $8 \equiv -2 \pmod {10},$ so $8^2 \equiv (-2)^2 \equiv 2^2 \pmod {10}$ and similarly for the others.  The symmetry around $0$ will be true in any base.  The symmetry around the midpoint will be true in any even base because $(5-a)^2=25-10a+a^2, (5+a)^2=25+10a+a^2$ and $+10a \equiv -10a \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$.

The previous paragraph will prove the two digit case is symmetric around $50$, but is not sufficient to prove it is symmetric around $25$.  For that, write $(25+a)^2=625+50a+a^2, (25-a)^2=625-50a+a^2$ and $50a \equiv -50a \pmod {100}$.  This pattern will work for any base that is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.